# How can I use c# as parameter in JQuery .after() funcion?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, razor

When click a button, I want some elements repeat. Here is what I tried:

```
$(function () {
    $("#repeat").on('click', function () {
        var $self = $(this);
        $self.parent().after(
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.MaxDepartmentLevel; i++)
        {
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                @if (i == 0)
            {
                    @Html.Label((i + 1) + "级单位", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedDepartmentIds[0][i], Model.Departments,
                        "请选择单位", new { @class = "form-control department" })
            }
            else
            {
                    @Html.Label((1 + i) + "级单位", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedDepartmentIds[0][i], Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(),
                        "所有单位", new { @class = "form-control department" })
            }
            </div>

            }

            );
    });
});
```

The code as parameter in `.after()` is c#, which is used to generate some dropdown lists. However, vs hints that there are many error here. I guess the way I use `.after()` is not correct. Please point out, thanks.

Comment: This is a whole lot of mixing of code.  But if the result is all one big HTML string inside of `after()` then you would just need to wrap that string in quotes in the JavaScript.

Comment: @David I wraped that string in quotes, however, when clicking button in order to repeat elements, the plain code just display, not running as c# code.

Comment: @David That is to say, `@for (var i = 0; i < Model.MaxDepartmentLevel; i++)...` just display in web page.

Comment: Of you're seeing C# code client-side then the C# code isn't running in the first place.  Where are you putting this code?  Is in a view, or are you trying to put this in a JavaScript file or something?

Comment: @David This code is in a `.js` file, which is referenced by a `.cshtml`(view) through `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/addDepartmentRange.js")`.

Comment: A JavaScript file isn't a view, you can't put C# code in there.  Put this in a `script` block in an actual view so the rendering engine can process the C# code.  (Or at the very least put the part which generates a client-side HTML string in the view and store it in a variable, which the `.js` file could use.)

Comment: @David Thanks, it works!

Comment: Or generate JS by renaming it to "addDepartmentRange.js.cshtml" (make sure to set null layout for it so).